# Is there anyway to return something from socket.io method in Swift?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sockets, socket.io

I'm constructing a socket method which the server side would passes a JSON array to the client side.

Afterward, I'd like to pass the data around for the use of other functions.

But the socket method in Swift limits me from doing so because it is a void function

This is the example of method
[image: code]

Nothing can escape from that closure {} and it seems like I can only do operations within the socket method

Is there any workaround where I can manipulate the socket method so that I get the data out of that scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know specifically about socket.io but if it's a classic situation of asynchronous operation, you could wrap your socket.io call in a new completion handler, for example:

```
// I suppose the data is of type NSData.
func readDataFromSocketIO(completion: (data: NSData) -> ()) {
    socket.on("connect") { data, ack in
        // ...
        completion(data: data)
    }
}
```

And you call it with a trailing closure:

```
readDataFromSocketIO() { data in
    // use `data` here
}
```

If you want to populate a property:

```
var dataFromSIO: NSData? {
    didSet {
        print("We got new data!")
    }
}

func populate() {
    readDataFromSocketIO() { data in
        self.dataFromSIO = data
    }
}
```

Of course these are just some simplistic examples, there's many ways to do this, you'll have to adapt it to your own classes and methods.

Also, note that I'm not a socket.io user and I didn't test my code examples in Xcode but they should be correct if my diagnostic for this issue is right.